# DELETE rows where userID is not found in separate table

Tags: mysql

If I run the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `user-data` t1 
LEFT JOIN `users` t2 ON t1.userID = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

It gives me all the rows that don't have a matching row in the `users` table, (because the user has been deleted).  But I cannot simply turn this into a `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE FROM `user-data` t1 
LEFT JOIN `users` t2 ON t1.userID = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

As I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't1 
LEFT JOIN `users` t2 ON t1.userID = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL' at line 1
```

What can I do to delete all the rows in `user-data` that don't have an existing user in table `users`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `IS NULL` try a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. Something like this:

```
DELETE t1
FROM user-data t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT id FROM FROM users WHERE user-data.userID = users.id)
)
```

Comment: Close! It worked with a little modification: `DELETE FROM `user-data` WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE `user-data`.userID = `users`.id)`

Comment: ahh yeahhh - miss read it, Glad it worked. `WHERE NOT EXISTS` are usually better for performance too

Comment: Yes thank you - I'd forgotten about that statement :)

Comment: While valid and perhaps even the best answer, this doesn't actually answer the original question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, true - adding the alias after the delete should fix the one

Comment: Incidentally, the delete query you wrote _doesn't_ need an alias after `DELETE`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because there's no confusion between the tables as there isn't a join?

Answer (score 1):

A delete join query is absolutely valid in MySQL.  I think the issue is that you did not specify an alias *after* `DELETE`.  Hence, the following should work:

```
DELETE t1 FROM `user-data` t1 
LEFT JOIN `users` t2
    ON t1.userID = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

I suspect the need for an alias here arises because it is not clear from *which* table we want MySQL to do a deletion.  Note that using the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` approach does not require an alias after `DELETE`.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember that you cannot use table aliases in a `DELETE`. Also you can specify the table where you want to delete from like this:

```
DELETE `user-data`.* FROM `user-data`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `user-data`.userID = `users`.id 
WHERE `users`.id IS NULL
```

Comment: still not valid, i'm afraid :( thanks for trying though!

Comment: you can, you just need to use it in the delete statement - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122767/can-i-use-table-aliases-in-a-mysql-delete-statement